# Can anyone explain why setting \lineskiplimit breaks align?

Tags: amsmath, line-spacing, incompatibility

OK, so this is a follow-up to [one of my previous questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49072/is-changing-lineskiplimit-to-some-negative-value-a-good-idea-and-what-the-valu):

If you uncomment the `\lineskiplimit` line, LaTeX goes crazy.  Why?  Does anyone have an idea how to fix it (without manually changing `\lineskiplimit` temporarily, or hacking into `amsmath`, which seems a bit nightmare-ish)?

```
\documentclass{article}

%\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
A sample aligned equation:
\begin{align*}
  c^2&=a^2+b^2
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you find one of the reasons: `amsmath.sty` says

```
\def\@display@init#1{%
    \global\dt@ptrue \spread@equation
    \everycr{%
        \noalign{%
            #1%
            \ifdt@p
                \global\dt@pfalse
                \vskip-\lineskiplimit
                \vskip\normallineskiplimit
            \else
                \penalty\@eqpen \global\dspbrk@lvl\m@ne
            \fi
        }%
    }%
}
```

and this of course has quite a bizarre consequence:

```
Overfull \vbox (15864.60002pt too high) has occurred while \output is active
```

It's *not* a good idea to set `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen` except in very controlled situations such as tabulars where struts can be inserted (and are, actually).

Comment: Thanks, but what sense does it make to `\vskip` `-\lineskiplimit` and then `\normallineskiplimit`!?

Comment: OK, I guess I understand: the second one may get discarded, and we might want exactly this.  So what should I do if I actually *want* a negative `\lineskiplimit` in my document?  Any idea?

Comment: OK, so I asked this in a separate question.

Comment: Link to the [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49317/how-to-do-grid-typesetting-with-amsmath)