# What does \normallineskiplimit do?

Tags: amsmath, line-spacing

In [this excellent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188503/484), one of the tools used is to redefine `\normallineskiplimit`. I cannot find this macro in any reference, although it does show up in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49312/484). Where is this length originally defined, and what exactly does this macro control?

A good answer may need to address related macros (if they exist) such as `\normallineskip`.

Comment: LaTeX defines the registers `\normalbaselineskip`, `\normallineskip` and `\normallineskiplimit` to store the standard values (defined by the font size option) in order to have those value still available when `\baselineskip`, `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit` change. For instance, in `tabular`, `\baselineskip` is set to zero, but you can always refer to `\normalbaselineskip` for using the normal value in spacing commands. I'd be wary of resetting their values.

Comment: Why I set `\normallineskiplimit` in my macro? Because I traced `{align*}` macro and I found that there is `\vskip-\lineskiplimit` immediatelly followed by `\vskip\normallineskiplimit`. We need zero `\vskip` as the result.

Answer (score 10):

`\normallineskiplimit` (and friends) are used in two places in latex,

they are used in `\@arrayparboxrestore`

```
\lineskip\normallineskip
\baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
```

so that inside `\parbox` and `minipage` and tabular `p` columns the baselineskip is restored to a normal state even if used in a context where they ave non standard values.

`\displaylines` compensates for non standard values of `\lineskiplimit`

```
\def\displ@y{\global\dt@ptrue\openup\jot\m@th
  \everycr{\noalign{\ifdt@p \global\dt@pfalse \ifdim\prevdepth>-1000\p@
      \vskip-\lineskiplimit \vskip\normallineskiplimit \fi
      \else \penalty\interdisplaylinepenalty \fi}}}
```

but that is really a hangover from plain TeX and not used much in LaTeX.

However the AMS alignments all reset this in a similar way `amsmath` has

```
\def\@display@init#1{%
    \global\dt@ptrue \spread@equation
    \everycr{%
        \noalign{%
            #1%
            \ifdt@p
                \global\dt@pfalse
                \vskip-\lineskiplimit
                \vskip\normallineskiplimit
            \else
                \penalty\@eqpen \global\dspbrk@lvl\m@ne
            \fi
        }%
    }%
}
```

to adjust for the difference between the current value of `\lineskiplimit` and the saved `\normallineskiplimit`

You can also use `\normalbaselines` to explicitly reset the values to defaults

```
\def\normalbaselines{\lineskip\normallineskip
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip \lineskiplimit\normallineskiplimit}
```

but I'm pretty sure I've never needed to do that:-)

Comment: The `\normalbaselines` macro is very known in plain TeX. It is used in `\cases` and `\matrix` macros.